# How to sort a ruby array in ascending order but keep zero last

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to sort a Ruby array with the following function

```
@prices = @item.prices.sort { |x,y| x.total <=> y.total }
```

Which orders from the lowest to the highest cost. However some products have a total of 0.00 and I want them to appear last rather than at the top.

I have tried a few things but would like some way to modify this block to sort zero at the bottom but keep the rest in ascending order.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So devise a comparator to do that ...

```
if x.total == 0
  # always consider 0 "largest" and no 0 can be larger than another
  # (make sure 0.0 is 0 and not a number really close to 0)
  # perhaps x or y should be first for other reasons as well?
  1
else
  # otherwise lower to higher as normal
  x.total <=> y.total
end
```

Or without comments:

```
foo.sort {|x, y| if x.total == 0 then 1 else x.total <=> y.total end}
```

Happy coding.

Comment: if you like conditional operator and a desperate one liner `foo.sort {|x, y| x.total.zero? ? 1 : x.total <=> y.total }`

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The problem is that it only checks `x.total == 0`, but it should also check `y.total == 0` and return 1 in that case too. Otherwise for some arrays you do not get the desired result, for example: `[2, 1, 0].sort{|x, y| if x == 0 then 1 else x <=> y end}` gives `[0, 1, 2]`. (Note I skipped the `.total` part for simplicity but the problem is the same.)

Comment: Small correction: I should have said "return -1 when `y.total == 0`. So, the corrected answer would read: `foo.sort{|x, y| next 1 if x.total == 0; next -1 if y.total == 0; x.total <=> y.total}`. Same as the answer by @ctcherry below.

Answer (score 3):

Try this out, I think it is doing what you request:

```
@prices = @item.prices.sort {|a,b| a.total==0 ? 1 : b.total==0 ? -1 : a.total<=>b.total}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for the record:

```
>> a = [0, 1, 3, 0, 2, 5, 0, 9]
=> [0, 1, 3, 0, 2, 5, 0, 9]
>> a.sort_by { |x| x.zero? ? Float::MAX : x }
=> [1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 0, 0, 0]
```

On most platforms `1.0/0` will evaluate to `Infinity`, so you can also use this instead of `Float::MAX`:

```
>> b = [1,4,2,0,5,0]
=> [1, 4, 2, 0, 5, 0]
>> Inf = 1.0/0
=> Infinity
>> b.sort_by { |x| x.zero? ? Inf : x }
=> [1, 2, 4, 5, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
prices = [0, 1, 2, 0,4, 3]
prices = prices.sort_by do |price|
  [
    if price == 0
      1
    else
      0
    end,
    price
  ]
end
p prices
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0]
```

The trick here is that arrays are compared by comparing their first elements, but if those elements are equal, then by comparing their next elements, and so on.  So having the sort_by block yield an array lets you determine primary sort order, secondary sort order, and so on in a clean manner.

Answer (score 0):

This would feel less hacky and less write-only to me:

```
prices = prices.sort_by do |price| 
  zero_status = price.zero? ? 1 : 0
  [zero_status, price]
end
```

because it's an idiomatic way of sorting something by two criteria, which is what you're doing here.

Comment: @aclarke you can't compare `false` against `true`. Your code would result in `ArgumentError: comparison of Array with Array failed`.